# Hartshorne IV Ex. 4.6(a) (Counting inflection points on plane curves)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The problem is as follows: Let $X$ be a curve of degree $d$ embedded into $\mathbf{P}^2$ with $r$ nodes. Show that the number of inflection points of $X$ is $6(g-1)+3d$ (nodes do not count as inflection points).

To answer this, I will use three pieces of data: first is the degree formula for singular curves. I should have $g_X=\frac{1}{2}(d-1)(d-2)-r$.

Second, I will use the fact that if we define a map $X \mapsto L$ by $x \mapsto T_x(X) \cap L$ for some $\mathbb{P}^1$ named $L$ (where $L$ is chosen not tangent to X in $\mathbb{P}^2$), this morphism has degree $d(d-1)$. Moreover, this map is ramified if and only if $x$ is an inflection point or $x$ lies on $L$.

Lastly I will use the Hurwitz theorem: given a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ of curves, $2g_X-2=d_f(2g_Y-2)+deg(R)$, where $d_f$ is the degree of $f$ and $R$ is the ramification divisor on $X$.

Putting all of this together (i.e. writing down the Hurwitz theorem when $f: X \rightarrow L$ is of degree $d(d-1))$ leaves me with $d^2-3d-2r=-2d(d-1)+deg(R)$, or $3d^2-5d-2r=deg(R)$. Subtracting off $d$ from both sides (so as to not count the ramification points where $L$ intersects $X$) I get $3d^2-6d-2r$.

This is close to what is written: using the degree-genus formula again I would expect $6(g-1)+3d$ to be equal to $3d^2-6d-6r$. How do I account for the difference in these two answers?

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes here: computing the degree of $\varphi$ (denoting the map $P \mapsto T_PX \cap L$) and applying Hurwitz' theorem to the wrong maps. Both of these stem from treating the singular projection like a smooth curve.

To fix some notation, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ the nodal curve obtained from projecting the smooth curve $\tilde{X}$ to $X$. Now, as you stated correctly, the genus of $\tilde{X}$ is $\frac{1}{2} (d - 1)(d - 2) - r$ since we have to take into account the $r$ nodes.

I am also struggling with working out the details of this exercise. In particular, the exercise seems to rely on this key assumption which I have not yet justified:

> Let $\varphi: X \dashrightarrow L$ be a finite rational map of curves where $L \cong \mathbb{P}^1$, and is chosen as in the problem. We may then take the ramification locus $\operatorname{Supp} R$ of the induced map $\varphi: \tilde{X} \to Y$ to lie in the smooth locus of $X$, viewed as an open subset of $\tilde{X}$.

Now that we have this, it makes sense to apply the solution to the previous exercise which identifies ramification points of $\varphi$ with $\{P \in X \;|\;P \text{ is an inflection point or } P \in X \cap L\}$. Similarly if we fix a sufficiently general $O \in \mathbb{P}^2 - X$, we can project from $O$ to get a morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$, and hence one $\tilde{X} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$. Using this assumption again, we see that the ramification points of this map correspond to the distinct tangent lines of $X$ passing through $O$. (see exercise IV.2.2(c)) The degree of the corresponding ramification divisor is easily seen to be the degree of $\varphi$.

We can then use Riemann-Hurwitz to compute this to be $$\deg R = 2d + 2g(\tilde{X}) - 2 = 2d + (d - 1)(d - 2) - 2r = d(d - 1) - 2r.$$

Now that we know $\deg(\varphi) = d(d - 1) - 2r$, we apply Hurwitz to the first map $\varphi: \tilde{X} \to L$. We subtract $d$ to disregard the points of $X \cap L$.

\begin{align*}
\deg R - d &= 2(d(d - 1) - 2r) + (d - 1)(d - 2) - 4r - 2 - d\\
&=3d^2 - 6d - 6r
\end{align*}

which is what we needed.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled - you say you're struggling with the details, but it seems you've worked out the right fix. Is there more you feel like you need for this? (Separately, it might help your answer a little if you actually show a little of the arithmetic at the end. I'm around to assist a bit with that or anything else if you'd like.)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! I actually missed an issue so the arithmetic wouldn't have worked out, which made me add some more detail. There's just one step(not the one being asked about) that I think is required but I don't know how to justify it. I included it in the answer.

Comment: In this case you can get around the ramification issue by requiring that the point you project from not be on the tangent lines to any of the nodes (to make this precise, if $N$ is a nodal point, you want the line $\overline{ON}$ to have intersection multiplicity 2 with $X$ at $N$) - this will give you that none of points over the nodes are ramified and therefore the ramification divisor is supported on the smooth locus. Add to this the standard assumptions on not being on any inflectional or multiple tangents and you have a recipe for success.

Comment: @KReiser This certainly clears up how to ensure that the ramification of the projection from $O$ lands in the smooth locus. I still don't quite see how to ensure the same with $\varphi$. Perhaps there's some way to move $L$ around as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't we already know the degree of $\varphi: X\to L$ from the degree of the projection from $O$? The conclusion from looking at the projection is that if you're a point not on a bad tangent line then there are the correct number of tangents through you. Now apply this to points on $L$ and conclude, once $L$ is chosen to only have finitely many points on bad tangent lines.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, we know the degree of $\varphi$, but I don't see how to conclude that the ramification locus $\tilde{X} \to L$ lands in the smooth locus of $X$. I worry that the bad points of $L$ might be branch points of $\varphi$.

Comment: My bad for focusing on the wrong part there. I think you might be correct, actually - for instance, the curve $V(xyz^2+x^4+y^4)$ has the origin count as an inflection point twice, once for the line $V(x)$ and once for $V(y)$ which have order of tangency 3 each along a branch at the node. So I guess Hartshorne has just been a little sloppy in what he means by "nodes don't count as inflection points". I can write up a little more about this in an answer if you wish. (Thanks for the push to figure out what's actually going on here!)

Comment: @KReiser No worries at all! Thank you for helping me understand. I'm glad that I wasn't just confused. Is the main idea to just generalize the notion of 'inflection points' to general cuves in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and then use that those are counted by the ramification?

Comment: Yep, that's how I'd respond to this situation. I'd probably say something along the lines of "a point $\widetilde{x}$ in the normalization $\widetilde{X}$ lying over a singular point $x\in X$ is an inflection point iff there exists a hyperplane $H\subset\Bbb P^2$ through $x$ so that the local equation of $H$ has valuation at least 3 in $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X},\widetilde{x}}$". This leads nicely in to the next part of the problem too, so that's fun too.